# Spaces in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am working on an app in which I am using `UIWebView`, when the webpage loads it adds space in the screen see below

[image]

Below is the code I have tried,

```
let requestURL = NSURL(string: "url")

 let request = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

 webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)

 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
 //webView.scrollView.contentInset.right = UIEdgeInsets.zero.right
```

nothing works.

Comment: Try this `webView.scalesPageToFit = true`

Comment: no , didn't worked :)

Comment: Can you add the url of the page here?

Comment: let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://fixplus.dexteroustech.net/en")

Comment: I does work for me, have you added proper Autolayout constraints to your WebView?

Comment: yes, gripped the webView from left,right,top,bottom and also fixed the height & width as same viewController

Comment: Try to load different web page

Comment: @Bilal See it works for me https://s9.postimg.org/hnhhe8527/web_View.png , I guess you have done some changes in the webview itself, try removing and re-adding a new UIWebView component.

Comment: @iphonic can you share the screen shot here or the constraints that you added.

Comment: @Bilal Yes sure [here it is](https://s3.postimg.org/a6i12w82b/Screen_Shot_2017_03_20_at_9_18_43_PM.png)

Comment: i added a new webView but it still scroll to the right , the width ain't getting fix

Comment: @iphonic are you sure , your screening is not scrolling to right or bouncing

Comment: because i did everything that u said :) but still my screening is scrolling to right

Comment: Ah yes it scrolls, this is website problem, your website is not compatible for mobile version so the scroll, I can see some of the images are there in the website which doesn't scale down on its own and bigger than the mobile screen and thus the scroll no problem with the code.

Comment: okay, thanks for your time :)